# How to create a SQLite database in a general java project (not specific to android) using Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I want to create a database for my android app.
At first, I want create it fully and then I will use it on my android project.
I can make sqlite database in SQLite IDE (sqlite database browser).
But I want to create it programmatically.
Because I will fetch data from a text file and push it to database.
It will be very fast and easier than IDE to make a database.
So my question, is there any way to make a SQLite database without SQLite database IDE in general java project (not specific to android) and what is that?
Thanks in advance.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41241/982149

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398575/sqlite-database-in-android-and-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically would just need to include the appropriate connection jars in your project and implement your own C.R.U.D. operations.   A quick google search comes up with a a bunch of good tutorials.  [Here's a basic one to start with.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this project https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc. I've used it in several projects. very good.